# JavaFX HyperLink focus rectangle default style

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there an easy way to change that ugly dashed-line focus rectangle on a focused Hyperlink to something else?  Either a solid line, maybe change the background color instead, etc.?  (I need focus indicator functionality, just want to change it a little.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default settings for `.hyperlink:focused` in modena.css are

```css
.hyperlink:focused {
    -fx-border-color: -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-border-style: segments(0.166667em, 0.166667em);
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

So something like

```css
.hyperlink:focused {
    -fx-border-color: null ;
    -fx-border-style: solid ;
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
    -fx-underline: true ;
}
```

in an external CSS file should work. (You could use `-fx-background-color: something ;` to change the background...)